# if text input equals go to webpage

Tags: html

I am currently using ionos for my website and i no coding experience at all, hoping for html help in doing this
I have 12 codes abcd, abce, abcf, abcg, abch, abci, abcj, abck, abcl, abcm, abcn, abco
If a person types in the input box abcd then select submit they will be directed to mywebpage/abcd
If the text = abce they will be directed to webpage mywebpage/abce and so on
I also don't know how to make the input box or the submit button.
Any help really appreciated

I have tried nothing as i don't know where to begin
I have only the widget to enter html code

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Comment: Have you tried googling it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello, martinsteel! I was looking at your question, and found a good answer. What I decided to do was replace the location with whatever the user typed in and clicked submit, here's the code:

```js
function goToPage() {
//You could do this, or individually for each link:
var theValue = document.getElementById("userValue").value;
location.replace("https://website.com/" + theValue)
//Obviously, change 'https://website.com/' to your website name.
//If you're already in your website, just put theValue in location.replace.
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userValue">
<button onClick="goToPage()">Submit</button>
```

Of course, you said you only wanted 12 options, abce, abcd, etc. You could individually type out each value option, (copy paste), but this is much more efficient and resource saving. If you were to do this option, you would have to create an if statement if the value contains any code in an array, which you could put all your links in. Then, you could use the location.replace() function to replace the link you are on with the one they typed in.

Hope this helps!!